# Scala apply method call as parentheses conflicts with implicit parameters

Tags: scala, apply, implicit-parameters

There is a note in Cay Horstmann's book "Scala for the Impatient" about the apply method:

> Occasionally, the () notation conflicts with another Scala feature:
>   implicit parameters. For example, the expression `"Bonjour".sorted(3)`
>   yields an error because the sorted method can optionally be called
>   with an ordering, but 3 is not a valid ordering.

The solution is to assign `"Bonjour".sorted` to a variable and call apply on it, for example:

```
val result = "Bonjour".sorted
result(3)
```

Or call apply explicitly:

```
"Bonjour".sorted.apply(3)
```

But why this doesn't work and produces a compile error:

```
("Bonjour".sorted)(3)
```

The sorted method returns a `String`, which can be imlicitly converted to a `StringOps` and parentheses are used to wrap the string expression.
Why compiler doesn't accept to call the apply method of a `StringOps`?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `-Xprint:parser` to see that the parens are discarded early:

```
scala> implicit class x(val s: String) { def scaled(implicit i: Int) = s * i }
defined class x

scala> "hi".scaled(5)
res0: String = hihihihihi

scala> { implicit val n: Int = 5 ; "hi".scaled }
res1: String = hihihihihi

scala> "hi".scaled(5)(3)
res2: Char = i

scala> { implicit val n: Int = 5 ; ("hi".scaled)(3) }
res3: String = hihihi

scala> :se -Xprint:parser

scala> { implicit val n: Int = 5 ; ("hi".scaled)(3) }
[[syntax trees at end of                    parser]] // <console>
package $line8 {
  object $read extends scala.AnyRef {
    def <init>() = {
      super.<init>();
      ()
    };
    object $iw extends scala.AnyRef {
      def <init>() = {
        super.<init>();
        ()
      };
      import $line3.$read.$iw.$iw.x;
      object $iw extends scala.AnyRef {
        def <init>() = {
          super.<init>();
          ()
        };
        val res4 = {
          implicit val n: Int = 5;
          "hi".scaled(3)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

res4: String = hihihi

scala>
```

The extra parens do nothing. The compiler just sees an application `expr(args)`. Because it's an application, you don't get "implicit application" conversion.

In any case, the meaning of `scaled`, a method, depends on the expected type.

The reason we expect the extra parens to make a difference is that parens override precedence of operators. But `(x)` is just `x`.

Possibly the spec is actually clear about this:

`e(args)` requires that `e` be applicable to the `args`. In particular, the args are typechecked according to the parameter types of `e`.

`e(args)` is taken as `e.apply(args)` if `e` is a value, but `scaled` is a method.

You're hoping for "implicit application" to insert the implicit args, but that only applies when `e` is not already applied. Or that `(e)(args)` could be taken as `(e(_))(args)`, that is, `(x => e(x))(arg)`.

When written as `e.apply(arg)`, the `e` is not an application like `e(arg)`, so you benefit from conversions like implicit application.

Comment: So, parentheses around ("Bonjour".sorted) doesn't force Scala compiler to call sorted function, but evaluates as a function reference, but parentheses after sorted(_) does a function call.

Comment: I wrote different words, but it took me longer to do. The extra parens do nothing. The compiler just sees an application `expr(args)`. Because it's an application, you don't get "implicit application" conversion. Hey, I did it. I'll add those words, too.