# Scala Map's get vs apply operation: "type mismatch"

Tags: scala, implicit, syntactic-sugar

I am learning Scala and found the following:

```scala
List(('a', 1)).toMap get 'a'           // Option[Int] = Some(1)
(List(('a', 1)).toMap) apply 'a'       // Int = 1
(List(('a', 1)).toMap)('a')            // Error: type mismatch;
                                          found   : Char('a')
                                          required: <:<[(Char, Int),(?, ?)
                                          (List(('a', 1)).toMap)('a')
```

But then assigning it to a variable works again.

```scala
val b = (List(('a', 1)).toMap)
b('a') // Int = 1
```

Why is this so?

The standard docs gives:

> `ms get k`
>
> The value associated with key k in map ms as an option, None if not found.
>
> `ms(k)`   (or, written out, `ms apply k`)
>
> The value associated with key k in map ms, or exception if not found.

Why doesn't the third line work?

Comment: There are many things happening here. First, your examples are incorrect. `get` as the documentation explains, returns an **Option** while `apply` returns a plain value. If the key does not exists, `get` will return an **None**, whereas `apply` will throw an **Exception**  - Second, the problem is that, `toMap` receives some implicit arguments. That is why it is better to split the code in two lines, because it confuses your `apply` with passing those arguments.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Have corrected the examples, thanks for pointing this out. Could you please explain the "implicit arguments"?

Comment: @LieuZhengHong It's a good question, and the behavior really is counter-intuitive. Does [this duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50259606/scala-apply-method-call-as-parentheses-conflicts-with-implicit-parameters) answer your question? Essentially, it attempts to treat `'a'` as an implicit argument to `toMap`. This here works: `(List((1, 2)).toMap(implicitly[(Int, Int) <:< (Int, Int)]))(1)`. This also works: `List((1, 2)).toMap.apply(1)`. But with just the parens, it doesn't work, for questionable reasons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's essentially just an idiosyncratic collision of implicit arguments with `apply`-syntactic sugar and strange parentheses-elimination behavior.

As [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50259606/scala-apply-method-call-as-parentheses-conflicts-with-implicit-parameters), the parentheses in

```
(List(('a', 1)).toMap)('a')
```

are discarded a bit too early, so that you end up with

```
List(('a', 1)).toMap('a')
```

so that the compiler attempts to interpret `'a'` as an implicit evidence of `(Char, Int) <:< (?, ?)` for some unknown types `?`, `?`.

This here works (it's not useful, it's just to demonstrate what the compiler would usually expect at this position):

```
(List(('a', 1)).toMap(implicitly[(Char, Int) <:< (Char, Int)]))('a')
```

Assigning `List(...).toMap` to a variable also works:

```
({val l = List((1, 2)).toMap; l})(1)
```

Alternatively, you could force `toMap` to stop accepting arguments by feeding it to `identity` function that does nothing:

```
identity(List((1, 2)).toMap)(1)
```

But the easiest and clearest way to disambiguate implicit arguments and `apply`-syntactic sugar is to just write out `.apply` explicitly:

```
List((1, 2)).toMap.apply(1)
```

I think at this point it should be obvious why `.get` behaves differently, so I won't elaborate on that.

Answer (score 1):

The [signature](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Map.html) is slightly different:

```
abstract def get(key: K): Option[V]

def apply(key: K): V
```

The issue is error handling: `get` will return `None` when an element is not found and `apply` will throw an exception:

```
scala> Map(1 -> 2).get(3)
res0: Option[Int] = None

scala> Map(1 -> 2).apply(3)
java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found: 3
  at scala.collection.immutable.Map$Map1.apply(Map.scala:111)
  ... 36 elided
```

Regarding the failing line: toMap has an implicit argument `ev: A <:< (K,V)` expressing a type constraint. When you call `r.toMap('a')` you are passing an explicit value for the implicit but it has the wrong type. Scala 2.13.0 has a companion object `<:<` that provides a reflexivity method (using the given type itself instead of a proper sub-type). Now the following works:

```
scala> List(('a', 1)).toMap(<:<.refl)('a')
res3: Int = 1
```

Remark: i could not invoke `<:<.refl` in Scala 2.12.7, the addition seems to be quite recent.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have made the question more specific. I understand the difference between Option vs throwing exception. I suppose my main confusion is why assigning to a val works, but putting it all on one line doesn't.

Comment: I just realized that `toMap` has an implicit argument: `def toMap[K, V](implicit ev: <:<[A, (K, V)]): immutable.Map[K, V]` which provides a witness object for type coercion. Scala tries to call that one instead of `apply`. I haven't found out yet how to create a default witness to pass. Then it should work by calling `List(('a',1)).toMap(ev)('a')`.

Comment: Added the explanation

Comment: Thanks for `<:<.refl`, didn't know about that.

Comment: According to the git history, it was added in December 2018, it might only have recently surfaced in the release version.